# Trouble adding a javascript function onto a Wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am trying to include a javscript function/plugin into a wordpress theme page. I just wanted the plugin to work on one particular page since it is supposed to be a sort of calendar plugin.

So as of right now I went ahead and used the wp_enqueue_script function in the functions.php file of the theme. This is what the code looks like:

```
function spacious_scripts(){
wp_enqueue_script('LaunchWS', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/wsLaunch.js');
}
add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'spacious_scripts');
```

I have also went ahead and created a js file out of the script provided to me by the creators of this plugin (i'm including it in case the script is broken, I am still new to javascript): 
the file is called: "wslaunch.js" and the function is named: 'launchWS'.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function launchWS(winName) { 
    //window height and width
    myHeight = screen.height*.80;
    myWidth = 784;
    //widow height bounds
    if ( myHeight < 556 ) {
        myHeight = 556;
    } else if (myHeight>700) {
        myHeight = 700;
    }

    //get screen size, and cacl center screen positioning
    var height = screen.height;
    var width = screen.width;
    var leftpos = width / 2 - myWidth / 2;
    var toppos = (height / 2 - myHeight / 2) - 40;

    //open window
    msgWindow=window.open(winName,"ws_window","toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,resizable=yes,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,status=yes,width=" 
                        + myWidth + ",height="+ myHeight + ", left=" 
                        + leftpos + ",top=" + toppos); 

    //focus window
    setTimeout('msgWindow.focus()',1);
}
```

So i don't know if that was enough but, I thought that i needed to add some code on the html editor of the page that i wanted to add this function to. I thought i needed to call the function and the javascript so I added this to the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/wslaunch.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
launchWS();
</script>
```

**Where am i going wrong?** Am I supposed to call the the function differently on the page itself? Am i supposed to include certain dependencies or specify the single events where the function should be enqueued in the function.php file itself??

Comment: Can you be specific about the error you're receiving? Or is nothing happening at all? If you're using chrome, right click anywhere and select inspect element to open the development console. From there click the "console" button at the top and see if any errors have been spit out. Paste them in here if so.

Comment: Please remove `<script type="text/javascript">` from `wsLaunch.js`, It may fix your problem.

Comment: These are the errors posted:     Failed to load resource:the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://shednshredhouston.com/js/wslaunch.js
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < wsLaunch.js:1;
    Uncaught ReferenceError: launchWS is not defined shednshredhouston.com/:202;
    Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document. gscs:12;

Comment: Remove script tag from you Javascript, if you want to call inline javascript in the header you can use 'wp_head' hook.